# Allow pasting text in Windows VNC client via simulated keystrokes

Tags: windows, keyboard, remote-desktop, vnc, clipboard

I would like to be able to paste local clipboard text into a remote VNC session via simulated keystrokes, as opposed to direct transfer of clipboard contents.

Why? I am using Veency VNC server on my iPhone and it does not appear to support VNC's clipboard synchronization. I just need to be able to paste text. Since I can use the local keyboard to type text into the remote session, I assume it should be pretty straight-forward to simulate keystrokes to paste clipboard text.

Comment: "I assume it should be pretty straight-forward to simulate keystrokes to paste clipboard text." Then why are you asking us?  ;)  What have you tried already?

Comment: I've tried nothing, and I'm all out of ideas. Well I did try a google search for 10 minutes and didn't find a quick solution, but point taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed the same and I found a solution good enough for me. I need to work with some systems via Remote Desktop where clipboard sharing is disabled in policy on the remote server and I needed to use my scripts there.
For me the solution is RoboTask - even the free Lite version is good enough.
http://robotask.com/download/

Specifically, create a task in RoboTask lite and add the following actions:

1. Get Text
2. Send keys to active window

Then choose a Triggering Event (I chose Shift+Ctrl+Ins).

Presto.

Comment: Why does this software solve the problem? Additionally I may have misunderstood you but the OP is asking about VNC solutions and you seem to be using RDC...

Comment: The Robotask "presses keys", no matter where you want them to be pressed - whether in VNC or RDP.

Comment: And this works on iOS does it? The OP is using a VNC client on his iPhone.

Comment: Just want to say a (very late) thanks. I ended up using RoboTask Lite and it does the job just fine. I've edited your answer (pending peer review) to include the exact steps needed for the task.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the open source application below does the same thing using AutoIt backend:

https://github.com/Collective-Software/ClickPaste